# Select all words with substring

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In a column there are some words with the same substring. In this case it is "book".

I need to extract all the words with this substring. How can it be done without programming?

In other words all the words should be moved to another che column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use [**Standard Filter**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-US/text/shared/02/12090100.html) - it's easy:

[image: Filter Word]

Comment: But I don't need those selected words in the column anymore. This method will not help me, if I'm not mistaken. In other words, I don't need to copy the cells, I need moving them to another place.

Comment: Just repeat the filtering with the "Does not contain - book" condition. You will have two lists - all words with the substring "book", and all other words. Replace the original list with the new list (regular cut-paste).